# Ksh cannot allocate memory linux

Tags: linux, ksh

I have two big arrays of strings (**each of them has ~90000 elems**).

I create them with `set -A` command.
And I need to figure out which of strings in first array don't have equal string in second.

My code:

```
for i in {0..${#hard_drive_files[*]}}; do          

    has_reference=false
    for j in {0..${#files_in_db[*]}}; do    
        if [[ ${files_in_db[j]} == ${hard_drive_files[i]} ]]; then
            has_reference=true
            break
        fi  
    done 

    if [[ $has_reference == false ]]; then
        echo "${hard_drive_files[i]}"
    fi     
done
```

This part of code "eats" too much memory. 
At the end of execution value of used memory is ~80000 MB

After this part of code I try to archive some files but get `cannot fork [Cannot allocate memory]`

Is there a solution for such problem?

P.S. 
kshVersion=Version AJM 93t+ 2010-02-02

To figure out how much ram memory is used I execute `free -m`

Comment: Did you consider using some other programming language (e.g. Ocaml, Python, C) to code your program? And I would guess that on Linux ash`or `zsh` are more common shells than `ksh`

Comment: sort both list, write to file, use `diff`.

Comment: new user tip: you may want to upvote/accept some answer if you find it useful or at least helpful.

Comment: edit your post to include the output of `print -- kshVersion=${.sh.version}`. Also, how are do you know that you're using ~80000MB of RAM for this?  Add this to your post also. ...  @j-16SDiZ 's solution is the more traditional and should work, but what you're doing seems like it should work (without my trying to simulate your issue).Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is specific reason to do it in Ksh ? Try to make some approximation of how much memory is needed for such table, and compare to amount of RAM and SWAP. I bet it's not a program specifically, but some per-process memory/swap usage limit in limits.conf or sysctl.conf.

You could also try to split data to some groups, by concept, like first letter of name or something, to decrease amount of needed memory. Your code probably is far from optimal, it will be better first to gather all information you need and then reuse it, instead of repeating whole procedure in nested loop like you're trying to do.